# How to get the list of csv files in a directory sorted by creation date in Python

Tags: python, csv, sortedlist

I need to get the list of ".csv" files in a directory, sorted by creation date.

I use this function:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, getctime

def get_sort_files(path, file_extension):
    list_of_files = filter(lambda x: isfile(join(path, x)),listdir(path)) 
    list_of_files = sorted(list_of_files, key=lambda x: getctime(join(path, x)))
    list_of_files = [file for file in list_of_files if file.endswith(file_extension)] # keep only csv files
    return list_of_files
```

It works fine when I use it in directories that contain a small number of csv files (e.g. 500), but it's very slow when I use it in directories that contain 50000 csv files: it takes about 50 seconds to return.

How can I modify it? Or can I use a better alternative function?

**EDIT1**:

The bottleneck is the `sorted` function, so I must find an alternative to sort the files by creation date without using it

**EDIT2**:

I only need the oldest file (the first if sorted by creation date), so maybe I don't need to sort all the files. Can I just pick the oldest one?

Comment: Might this question be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979891/python-combining-all-csv-files-in-a-directory-and-order-by-date-time)

Comment: The bottleneck isn't really the *sorted* function but the time spent executing *getctime* which we now know (from a comment to an answer) is probably due to the fact that the directory in question is on a network drive. A good test would be to run a timer on getting all the files and running *getctime* on each of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using os.scandir:

```
from os import scandir

def get_sort_files(path, file_extension):
    """Return the oldest file in path with correct file extension"""
    list_of_files = [(d.stat().st_ctime, d.path) for d in scandir(path) if d.is_file() and d.path.endswith(file_extension)]
    return min(list_of_files)
```

os.scandir seems to used less calls to stat. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829029/python-2-vs-3-slow-os-path-getmtime-with-huge-file-list-why) for details.
I could see much better performance on a sample folder with 5000 csv files.

Comment: Awesome! In my case it works in 0.3 seconds

Comment: Using `min(list_of_files, key=lambda x: x[0])` will get the oldest timestamp, and will be faster than `.sort()` by a tiny amount

Comment: Is it the same if I use `min(list_of_files)`, without `key=lambda x: x[0]`?

Comment: In this case, basically yes. Seet this [post on tuple comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python). Might be even more performant.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by only examining the creation time on relevant files. You can do this by using *glob()* to return the files of interest.

Build a list of 2-tuples - i.e., (creation time, file name)

A sort of that list will implicitly be performed on the first item in each tuple (the creation date).

Then you can return a list of files in the required order.

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join, getctime

def get_sort_files(path, extension):
    list_of_files = []
    for file in glob(join(path,f'*{extension}')):
        list_of_files.append((getctime(file), file))
    return [file for _, file in sorted(list_of_files)]

print(get_sort_files('some directory', 'csv'))
```

**Edit:**

I created a directory with 50,000 dummy CSV files and timed the code shown in this answer. It took 0.24s

**Edit 2:**

OP only wants oldest file. In which case:

```
def get_oldest_file(path, extension):
    ctime = float('inf')
    old_file = None
    for file in glob(join(path,f'*{extension}')):
        if (ctime_ := getctime(file)) < ctime:
            ctime = ctime_
            old_file = file
    return old_file
```

Comment: Thanks! But in my case it takes about 25 seconds (half of my function), that is still too much time

Comment: @nicc96 In that case it's not your code that's slow - it's your hardware. Ask yourself  how/why it could possibly run in under 1 second on my machine but not on yours. Are your CSVs on a network drive perhaps?

Comment: Yes, they are! and a file has a size of about 100 KB

Comment: @nicc96 The size of the file should be irrelevant as you're not opening them let alone reading them. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
def get_sort_files(path, extention):
    # Relative path generator
    sort_paths = (join(path, i)
                  for i in listdir(path) if i.endswith(extention))
    sort_paths = sorted(sort_paths, key=getctime)

    return sort_paths
```

```
# Include the . char to be explicit
>>> get_sort_files("dir", ".csv")
['dir/new.csv', 'dir/test.csv']
```

However, all file names are in a relative path; `folder/file.csv`. A slightly less efficient work-around would be to use a `lambda` key again:

```
def get_sort_files(path, extention):
    # File name generator
    sort_paths = (i for i in listdir(path) if i.endswith(extention))
    sort_paths = sorted(sort_paths, key=lambda x: getctime(join(path, x)))

    return sort_paths
```

```
>>> get_sort_files("dir", ".csv")
['new.csv', 'test.csv']
```

---

Edit for avoiding `sorted()`:

Using `min()`:

*This is the fastest method of all listed in this answer*

```
def get_sort_files(path, extention):
    # Relative path generator
    sort_paths = (join(path, i) for i in listdir(path) if i.endswith(extention))
    return min(sort_paths, key=getctime)
```

Manually:

```
def get_sort_files(path, extention):
    # Relative path generator
    sort_paths = [join(path, i) for i in listdir(path) if i.endswith(extention)]

    oldest = (getctime(sort_paths[0]), sort_paths[0])
    for i in sort_paths[1:]:
        t = getctime(i)
        if t < oldest[0]:
            oldest = (t, i)

    return oldest[1]
```

Comment: Thanks! But check my EDIT, I can't use the sorted() function

Comment: No worries @nicc96. Using `sorted` or not, you still need to rank the values, avoiding `sorted` will not fix your bottleneck. Nevertheless, I'll add an alternative to sorting.

Comment: @nicc96, see my example with `min()`, should be slightly faster. But as the other answer pointed out. The speed is lost from the files being on a network drive. Not from the code. Try downloading them and running this again

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
def get_sort_files(path, file_extension):
    list_of_files = [file for file in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, file)) and file.endswith(file_extension)]
    list_of_files.sort(key=lambda x: getctime(join(path, x)))
    return list_of_files
```

This version could have better performance especially on big folders. It uses a list comprehension directly at the beginning to ignore irrelevant files right from the beginning. It uses in-place sorting.

This way, this code uses only one list. In your code, you create multiple lists in memory and the data has to be copied each time:

1. `listdir(path)` returns the initial list of filenames
2. `sorted(...)` returns a filtered and sorted copy of the initial list
3. The list comprehension before the return statement creates another new list

Comment: Thanks but it still takes about 50 seconds